# Getting Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'. while generating signed apk

Tags: android, proguard, picasso, android-proguard, fastadapter

I'm trying to generate signed apk of my android app and the task is remaining unsuccessful giving me this error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.SingleLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.SingleLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.SingleLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.SingleLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.SingleLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.SingleLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.SingleLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.SingleLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.ThreeLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.ThreeLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.ThreeLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.ThreeLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.ThreeLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.ThreeLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.ThreeLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.ThreeLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.TwoLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.TwoLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.TwoLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.TwoLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.TwoLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.TwoLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.TwoLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.StringHolder
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.TwoLineItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.ImageHolder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentCircularArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentSequencedCircularArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.MpmcArrayQueueConsumerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.MpmcArrayQueueProducerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.MpscLinkedQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpmcArrayQueueConsumerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpmcArrayQueueProducerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscUnboundedArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.UnsafeAccess: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:there were 145 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 19.342 secs
Information:1 error
Information:69 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Here's my `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keep public class com.mikepenz.fastadapter
-keep public class com.squareup.picasso
-keep public class rx.internal.util.unsafe
```

Here's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:1.8.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions:1.8.0@aar'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.0'
    compile 'hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library:supernova-emoji-library:0.0.2'
    compile 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.1'
    compile 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.10@aar'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.coyarzun89:fabtransitionactivity:0.2.0'
    compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.codemybrainsout.rating:ratingdialog:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Why am I** getting these warnings and error and **how can I** get rid of them?

I tried searching the web and read this [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) here, but I'm still unable to figure out.

Please help me with this.

Comment: are you set progaurd rules and minify enabled to true?

Comment: @Ahamed yes, see the edited question

Comment: set false will solve this issue. but your apk size will be big.Faced this error long time before.

Comment: @Ahamed I know that and don't want to do this... any other solution?

Comment: Yes. you can download all repositories and paste it into your project . this will solve this issue.instead of using it in gradle.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya that didn't helped

Comment: @Ahamed what do you mean? please describe more clearly.

Comment: @HammadNasir once add  `-keep class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.** { *; }`  rule in proguard and try

Comment: @user1140237 it solved it for `mikepenz` library but what about `Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe` and related warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to include proguard exceptions for okhttp which is used by picasso. Add

```
# OkHttp
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

See [here](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/tree/master/libraries) for proguard configuration for other libraries you might be using.

Comment: it solved it for `squareup` library but what about `Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeR‌​ef: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe` and related warnings? There is no mention of this library in the link you've provided.

Comment: That is probably rxjava.

Comment: I removed `-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**` and came to know that I'm not getting the warning because of this. Does it means that the problem isn't solved? How could it affect the app?

Answer (score 1):

For

```
Warning:com.mikepenz.fastadapter_extensions.items.SingleLineItem:
```

Apply below Rule

```
-keep class com.mikepenz.materialize.holder.** { *; }
```

> From Comment discussion @user1140237 it solved it for mikepenz library
>   but what about
>   Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeR‌​ef:
>   can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe and related warnings?

Add below rule

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
```

[Check this link it my help you](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava)

For ok http or square related follow the answer given by JohnWowUs

Comment: how can using just `-dontwarn` and not resolving the issue have affects on the app and user experiennce?

Comment: @HammadNasir  Specifies not to warn about unresolved references and other important problems at all. The optional filter is a regular expression; ProGuard doesn't print warnings about classes with matching names. Ignoring warnings can be dangerous. For instance, if the unresolved classes or class members are indeed required for processing, the processed code will not function properly. Only use this option if you know what you're doing!  check https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage for more details on proguard